# Toon Shader not working in Object Mode (Display correctly in Edit Mode tho)

Tags: 3d-view, light

My toon shading does not display in Object Mode and i can't figure out why.
The weird thing is that if i switch to Edit Mode, i can see that my shader is working.
[image]

It however display correctly in Edit Mode

[image]

Did i missed any checkbox or something?
The node is really simple. On Object Mode, it display only the darker part of the shader.
Any idea why?